# RNB Calculator using a Linked list

Tags: c++

```
include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#include "Stack.h"

int main()
{
  Stack<float>b;
  Stack <float> a(b);
  char num[100];
  while (true)
  {

    cout << "Enter: " << endl;
    cin >> num;

    if(strcmp(num,"Q") == 0 ||strcmp(num,"q")==0)
      break;


    if(strcmp(num,"*")==0)
     {


     float num1 = b.pop();//Error: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'float' with an rvalue of type 'void'

     float num2 = b.pop();// Error: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'float' with an rvalue of type 'void'

     if(num1 && num2){

     a.push(num1*num2);

     }
```

This I a part of my program. the problem is that I need to store the value I pop from my list and then multiply them and store them back. Over here I am trying to store the values in float number so that I can do an operation but it gives me an error as stated above any help will be appreciated.

Comment: usually, `pop()` is used just to remove the item in the top of the stack, but does not return the value. You would have to call `top()`, which acturally retrieves the item in the top of the stack, then call `pop()` to remove the item and let the next one available. Thus, the code would become `float num1 = b.top(); b.pop();`. You would do the same everytime you want to retrieve the top of the head and remove it. However, this is theoretical, as I see you are using a custom Stack implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `"Stack.h"` is similar to `<stack>`:

Referring to [`Stack.pop()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/):

> **Return value**
>
> none

So you should use [`Stack.top()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/top/):

> **Return value**
>
> A reference to the top element in the stack.

**Sample Code**

```
float num = b.top(); // get top value of stack
b.pop(); // pop it, not used anymore
// do something with num here
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you

Comment: @HaiderBokhari, if this post helps, you can marked it as the answer. thanks